# Sending JSON Payload using Request::request_multiple()

Tags: http-api

I have an external api which takes json body as payload. I am trying to send multiple parallel requests. So I am not using `wp_remote_post()`

The wp_remote_post() version of my code works perfectly.

## Sending JSON payload using `wp_remote_post()`

This works!

```
        $response = wp_remote_post($url, [
            'body' => json_encode($registrants), // requried keys [firstName, lastName, email]
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            ],
            'data_format' => 'body',
            'timeout' => 10,
        ]);

        return json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
```

Now I am trying to do the same with [`Request::request_multiple()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/request_multiple/) But data isn't sending as json body.

## Sending JSON payload using `Request::request_multiple()`

Does not work!

```
    $requests[] = [
            'url' => $url,
            'type' => 'POST',
            'body' => json_encode($registrant), // requried keys [firstName, lastName, email]
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            ],
            'data_format' => 'body',
            'timeout' => 30,
        ];

    $options = [
        'data_format' => 'body'
    ];

    $resp = Requests::request_multiple($requests, $options);
    foreach($resp as $response){
        var_dump($response);
        $responses[] = json_decode($response->body);
    }
```

The error I am getting from API is very specific and throws when it doesn't get JSON body payload.

Comment: I've digged through the code of the requests library, I don't beliieve `request_multiple` works the same way as the other request methods. It looks like it only supports a lmiited subset of parameters, `body` isn't included `* @param array $requests Request data (array of 'url', 'headers', 'data', 'options') as per {@see Requests_Transport::request}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.**

The requests library that comes bundled in WordPress doesn't support this. The reason for this is that the `request_multiple` function only accepts these parameters:

```
* @param array $requests Request data (array of 'url', 'headers', 'data', 'options') as per {@see Requests_Transport::request}
```

`body` is not one of those parameters, which explains why your request is failing. A reading of the code confirms this is the case down to the fsock/curl levels of the library.

Instead:

- Perform non-parallel requests if you intend to continue using the `Requests` library
- Switch to an alternative library such as Guzzle

I'd also recommend opening issues on GitHub, there doesn't appear to be any technical reason it couldn't be changed to support the `body` parameter other than that nobody added it when those interfaces were written

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that the $registrant variable is spelled differently in the two cases?

If this is not a problem try printing out the value of `json_encode($registrant)` before you send it and see if it looks right.

Comment: Yes, i have picked that part of the code from inside a loop. That is not an issue.

Comment: @Sisir so if you print it out, is it JSON? how are you going to debug it? what does the $registrant variable look like in the case where it works?